# RxSwift network status observable

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I have a method 'getProducts' in my view model:

```
struct MyViewModel {
    func getProducts(categoryId: Int) -> Observable<[Product]> {
        return api.products(categoryId: categoryId)
    }
    var isRunning: Observable <Bool> = {
        ...
    }
}
```

`api.products` is a private variable which uses `URLSession rx` extension: `session.rx.data(...)` in the background.

I would like to have some isRunning observer in my view model which I could subscribe to to know if it's do a network request.

Is it something I could do without making any amendments to my api class?

I'm new in reactive programming so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using a helper class written by RxSwift authors in [RxSwift Examples](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift) called `ActivityIndicator`.

The ideas is simple

```
struct MyViewModel {
    /// 1. Create an instance of ActivityIndicator in your viewModel. You can make it private
    private let activityIndicator = ActivityIndicator()

    /// 2. Make public access to observable part of ActivityIndicator as you already mentioned in your question
    var isRunning: Observable<Bool> {
        return activityIndicator.asObservable()
    }

    func getProducts(categoryId: Int) -> Observable<[Product]> {
        return api.products(categoryId: categoryId)
            .trackActivity(activityIndicator) /// 3. Call trackActivity method in your observable network call
    }
}
```

In related ViewController you can now subscribe to isRunning property. For instance:

```
    viewModel.isLoading.subscribe(onNext: { loading in
        print(loading)
    }).disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: What do I need to import to be able to call trackActivity on my observable?

Comment: The source file of ActivityIndicator (the link is posted in my answer) already contains method trackAcyivity as a part of ObservableConvertibleType extension

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.